# How add a custom text in share button facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to add a text in my post and I use:

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=***&sdk=joey&u=http://www.ansa.com/&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button"

I need to add a text when someone click on the button and they opened a windows from where the user can share. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share wont allow that. It'll fetch the og tags from the link and fill the contents in the dialog.

If you want to add cutomized description/picture/caption you should instead use [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3).

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
     app_id=1438439249728371
     &display=popup
     &caption={caption}
     &link={link-to-share}
     &description={description}
     &redirect_uri={redirect-url-to-your-site}
```

check here for more details:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3#params